# Insert base 64 encoded image into oracle database

Tags: oracle

I am working on hybrid mobile application in which I have a scenario to store images in to oracle database through web-API. I can get the images as base-64 encoded from API. So how can i save them to database and what datatype should I use to store them

Comment: Datatype to use is CLOB and we can just store the encoded string as it without any modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert image you can use `BLOB` data type . about how storing pictures in database check [storing pic and photos](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_storing_insert_photo_pictures_tables.htm) and [how to store image](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:239814548726)